# Why line-height affects to inline-flex? Any solution?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When multiple divs, some of them only 1 line text and other 2 with different line-height, positioned with inline-flex for content centering, they appear in different vertical positions. I know it's because of the line-height, when I put only 1 line text it doesn't happen. Need it without floats.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Sergio-Torres-the-reactor/pen/GRzvgpb

```css
#juego {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.juego_respuesta {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: block;
}

.juego_respuesta_botones {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.juego_respuesta_buton {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 11px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.juego_respuesta_buton span {
  font-size: 7px;
}

.juego_respuesta_buton:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.juego_respuesta_buton.activo {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="juego">
  <div class="juego_respuesta">
    <div class="juego_respuesta_botones">
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton activo">
        <div>TEST 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 3<br> TEST 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 4<br>
          <span>(TEST 4)</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 5<br>
          <span>(TEST 5)</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 8<br>
          <span>(TEST 8)</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried different heights/min-heights and display properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my initial look, you should give the flex display to parent element so it controls the positioning of the children buttons.

I modified the CSS a little bit and it fixes the issue.

```css
#juego {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.juego_respuesta {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.juego_respuesta_botones {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.juego_respuesta_buton {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 11px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;  
  margin: 10px 5px;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.juego_respuesta_buton span {
  align-self:center;
}
.juego_respuesta_buton:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.juego_respuesta_buton.activo {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="juego">
  <div class="juego_respuesta">
    <div class="juego_respuesta_botones">
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton activo">
        <div>TEST 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 3<br>
          TEST 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 4<br>
          <span>(TEST 4)</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 5<br>
          <span>(TEST 5)</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 8<br>
          <span>(TEST 8)</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="juego_respuesta_buton">
        <div>TEST 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```